# Change /home/opencart/public_html/opencart to localhost URL (Change Server URL to Localhost URL)

Tags: url, server, localhost, opencart

I am trying to move Hosted Opencart to XAMPP.
I have changed domain name to localhost/opencart but don't know how to change these URLs to localhost URL

/home/opencart/public_html/opencart

I tried searching in google but didn't found any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on which folder you want to install OpenCart.
You need to find absolute path to your directory. For example if you want to install OpenCart in a directory called opencart, create a `find_path.php` file in that folder with this content:

```
<?php
echo __DIR__;
```

Then run it in your browser:

```
http://localhost/opencart/find_path.php
```

You should see something like this on the screen:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\opencart

Another way is to install a fresh OpenCart in your localhost, and then look at the `config.php` file that is filled in by OpenCart.

Comment: Do I need to replace / with \ in windows machine?

Comment: Thanks A lot friend.

Comment: the path of DIR_APPLICATION has to be something like 'F:/xampp/htdocs/*******/catalog/' where you put your folder name in the place of the stars, and the same for the other defines in config.php